# How to handle unhelpful comments When trying to answer a question

Tags: discussion, comments

I provided an answer to a question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940001/error-with-the-right-function-in-sql-server/27940116#27940116)** which needed to some as it still didn't solve the OP's question but the only replies were pretty unhelpful.

```
It's not working –  Nida 10 mins ago

What is the error? –  Matt 9 mins ago   

Please provide me the correct code –  Nida 9 mins ago

what is the error your getting? –  Matt 9 mins ago   

It's not doing the accurate job –  Nida 8 mins ago

What ERROR message specifically are you getting? –  Matt 7 mins ago
```

When they are un-constructive like this what is the best way to handle it and get the information needed from them?

I don't want to come across as rude to them by any means but their responses are unhelpful.

Comment: To what unconstructive comment are you refering?

Comment: It's not working, Please provide me the correct code, It's not doing the accurate job.

Comment: Can't say I pity you, that's what happens when you provide free consulting for people who don't have the slightest clue what they're doing. One way to not have to deal with that is to _not answer questions by people who can't formulate a decent question_. The way the question is worded is a pretty big red flag here.

Comment: related: [Etiquette on How to Respond to False Accusations](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/246845/165773) at MSE

Comment: @gnat Thank you, i'll have a read.

Comment: Press the _Close Tab_ keyboard shortcut and slowly walk away. Pretend you never answered the question. (I know I'm an asshole)

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Not an asshole. That is the only way to handle it. If you don't respect your own time, no one else will either. =)

Comment: You should *never feel obligated* to help someone unconditionally. If you believe you've provided an honest answer that most people would find acceptable and helpful, then you shouldn't feel pressured into being pulled into a help vampire scenario.

Comment: Looks like you're the one who got screwed this time, Ron.

Comment: Even more fun, they *give* you the error message and its like 'mySampleVariable doesn't exist' when obviously that was a placeholder for something they didn't show. At that point, I leave a comment like "Its a local variable that you should already have" and begin the walking away process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, when I post an answer with any kind of substantial code, I've tested the code before posting. So I'm pretty sure it works. And I'm very careful about pasting code into answers.

When I get a comment that my code does not work, I evaluate whether the claim is plausible: is it likely that the problem reported in the claim in fact exists in my answer? If yes, then I check whether my answer is faulty. If not, then I ignore the comment. I consider a comment that states that *there is* a problem but does not specify *what the problem is* to be *implausible*.

It has happened quite a few times that after a few days of ignoring a comment from the OP about a problem, I'd get an upvote and the acceptance mark from the OP. Sometimes the OP has to just sort it out in their head.

There is a risk in ignoring the OP that you won't get an upvote and the acceptance mark from the OP. I'd sacrifice the reputation in favor of using my time more fruitfully.

Comment: Yeah, Its now went to the fact he has posted some alternative code in screenshots that have nothing to do with the original question so its kind of gone on a tangent.

Answer (score 3):

I personally see that this question shows confusion rather than actual request to interfere and help.

Surely,

> Please provide me the correct code

does have a notorious

> Give me teh codez

smell.

Although it is not *rude* as is it is somewhat too pushy to a person willing to devote his scarce resource - time - to solving someone else's problem. In fact, the answerer requested for clarification in order to provide an extra bit of help and that's a good point.

Basically this could stem from the fact that OP's level of English is not that good, not from the fact that OP wanted to be rude (consequently, the word "please"). But I don't see any unhelpfulness/rudeness in those comments. You should have probably helped OP gain more understanding on what you request.

You took it too personal and plausibly too hostile. Your point of view is understandable, but do answer for yourself: is the comment *that* offensive/rude to undertake some action as to put it in moderators review queue?

Comment: Yeh i removed the rude part a bit ago from my question as it does seem to be the level of english, but i dont want to come across as rude to him/her either

Comment: @Matt I can understand that you did some job in order to help and got a "give me a working solution" reference instead and that could be frustrating. But you need to get over it and move on and definitely not count that as personal.

Comment: Oh no, on the contrary I didn't take it personally at all, it was more of a; how to handle it to get the information needed from the OP without me sounding rude after asking 3 times

Comment: @Matt In your place I would do the following (in case you *really want to help*): reformulate the question so that it is clear and answerable (I see it as a good candidate for a close vote) and provide her with a clear feedback on what extra information you require.

Comment: Lets see how it pans out :) Its also now a candidate for reversal as it has received a few down votes :/

Comment: @Matt Ah you, posh badge-seeker :)

Comment: Says the Fanatical Steward!

Comment: @Matt Very true, Mr Unsung Hero :)

Comment: If it's not rude, it's certainly right on the borderline. Q: "I am hungry, please give me food." A: "Here you go, have a sandwich." Comment: "Please give me my favorite food." (Note that neither "favorite food" nor "correctness" are defined.)